# How I can get a pointer to the key in an unordered_map when I am iterating over it?

Tags: c++, iterator, unordered-map

coming from a C mindset I have very little experience with the c++ standard library and I wonder if anyone knows how I can get a pointer to the key in an unordered_map when I am iterating over it?
To be more specific, I am trying to do something like this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> my_map;
std::string *the_string_i_care_about;
for(auto& itr : my_map) {
    if (itr.first == "pick me!" ) {
        the_string_i_care_about = &itr.first;
    }
}
...
do stuff with the_string_i_care_about later
```

If it matters, in my real code I do not have a pair of string and int, but of two POD structs (I am mapping units to coordinates in a strategy game).

Comment: What's the issue with the code you've shown? Please provide any error messages, or incorrect results you get.

Comment: `&itr.first`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) stores key as `const`, its element's type is `std::pair<const Key, T>`; `the_string_i_care_about` should be pointer to `const` too. e.g.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> my_map;
const std::string *the_string_i_care_about;
for(auto& itr : my_map) {
    if (itr.first == "pick me!" ) {
        the_string_i_care_about = &itr.first;
    }
}
```

Comment: But if it is const it cannot change and the point of the code is that I might get a different key each time I iterate. In my example of course I would always get the string that is "pick me", but suppose I was checking for something more dynamic, like if the key was the coodinate I clicked on?

Comment: @SebastianJensen The pointer is not `const`, it can point to different strings at run-time. But if you want to point to the key in a `map` then it must be a pointer to a const string. You can still point it at different const strings at run-time.

Comment: @SebastianJensen You might use the wrong container; you can't and shouldn't modify on the key stored in `std::unordered_map` directly.